# Extract utility type breaks with "this"

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write an instance method in Typescript that accepts the name of one of the instance's attributes, but only if that attribute's name is a string. Why does `this.doStuff("name")` fail to compile?

Below is the shortest example I could come up with.

```
type StringAttributes<T> = Extract<keyof T, string>;

class Base {
  1337: string;
  name!: string;

  doStuff(attr: StringAttributes<this>): void {
    console.log(this[attr]);
  }

  doEverything() {
    const bar = new Base();
    // should compile
    bar.doStuff("name");

    // should compile (but doesn't)
    this.doStuff("name");

    // should not compile
    bar.doStuff("fizzbuzz");
    this.doStuff("fizzbuzz");

    // should not compile
    this.doStuff(1337);
    bar.doStuff(1337);
  }

  doEverythingWithType(this: Base) {
    const bar = new Base();
    // should compile
    bar.doStuff("name");

    // should compile
    this.doStuff("name");

    // should not compile
    bar.doStuff("fizzbuzz");
    this.doStuff("fizzbuzz");

    // should not compile
    this.doStuff(1337);
    bar.doStuff(1337);
  }
}
```

Comment: My best guess is this is a limitation of TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Your `StringAttributes` requires typescript to fully evaluate `keyof this`, which it can't do. Instead, use a generic with a bound:

```js
doStuff<T extends keyof this & string>(attr: T): void {
  console.log(this[attr]);
}
```

Or, as stated in the comments:

```js
doStuff(attr: keyof this & string): void {
  console.log(this[attr]);
}
```

Comment: No need to make `doStuff` generic; just changing `type StringAttributes<T> = keyof T & string;` is good enough.

Comment: Why do you say typescript can't evaluate `keyof this`? It seems to me like it can.

Answer (score 0):

`this` can't be fully understood by TypeScript, perhaps because the `this` variable could be altered by various things like `.bind()`?

Comment: I'm not sure I like my answer very much.